# Default value for -vm value in the eclipse.ini file

Tags: java, eclipse

What's the default value for -vm in the eclipse.ini file?. If I don't set this value, where the system will look for this value. Thanks!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html

> No -vm specified
>
> When no -vm is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine first in a jre directory in the root of eclipse and then on the search path. If java is found in either location, then the launcher looks for a jvm shared library (jvm.dll on Windows, libjvm.so on *nix platforms) relative to that java executable.
>
> - If a jvm shared library is found the launcher loads it and uses the JNI invocation API to start the vm.
> - If no jvm shared library is found, the launcher executes the java launcher to start the vm in a new process.